# Voltar linha do debug

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, debug

No antigo Visual Basic se você estivesse em `debug` passa-a-passo e sem querer passasse de um linha que queria verificar, havia a opção de ir com o cursor até a linha acima e pressionar a combinação de teclas: `Crtl + F9` para que `debug` voltasse para tal linha.

Existe essa opção (ou algo semelhante) no Visual Studio 2013 ?

Comment: Você pode arrastar com o mouse o ponto do debug no VS, tanto para frente quanto para trás...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Visual Studio, em modo de debug, aparece uma seta amarela do lado esquerdo do codigo.

Podes arrastar essa seta para cima, para voltar a executar codigo.